# How do I correctly bind a Typescript accessor decorator to the original instance?

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I want to decorate a property accessor on a Typescript class:

```
class Christmas {
  ...
   
  @decorated
  get tree() {
    return `Fraser fir with `${this.presents} under it`
  }
}
```

```
function decorated<R extends {}, P>(
  target:      R,
  propertyKey: keyof R,
  descriptor:  TypedPropertyDescriptor<P>
) {
  const accessor = descriptor.get
  descriptor.get = () => {
    console.log(`decorating ${propertyKey}`)
    return ???
  }
}
```

How do I call the original accessor inside the decorator? `accessor()`, `accessor.call(this)`, and `accessor.call(target)` all break the call to `this` inside `Christmas.tree`.

Comment: Use a decorator to decorate a christmas tree. That makes sense 

Answer (score 4):

You just have to handle the case when the decorator is not positioned on a getter, because its type is `(() => P) | undefined`.

Also, as your class could be inherited from, don't force `this` to `target`. Leave it as `this` and use a regular function instead of an arrow function.

```
function decorated<R extends {}, P>(
    target: R,
    propertyKey: keyof R,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<P>
) {
    const oldAccessor = descriptor.get;
    if (oldAccessor === undefined)
        throw 'Decorator is only allowed on getters';

    descriptor.get = function (this: R) {
        console.log(`decorating ${propertyKey}`);
        return oldAccessor.call(this);
    }
}

class Christmas {

    presents = 'presents';

    @decorated
    get tree() {
        return `Fraser fir with ${this.presents} under it`
    }
}

class ExtendedChristmas extends Christmas {
    presents = 'more presents';
}

const chris = new Christmas;
console.log(chris.tree);

const extChris = new ExtendedChristmas;
console.log(extChris.tree);
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgCYFMoIE4EMbqoA8ASsugB4ESoDOyA3gL4A0yACgHwAUwy-yGLmwBzdDABcyEiz4CADtgTz02GAE8A0unVSA1joQhpsgWnS0o2OPJg4pAFXUrU7JSrXqAIhas272ERcwACUjHL8WBC0MMgIADaoAIJQUBa0OMgAvOaW1rY4AHRiMADcEchwxtwJyanpmVlNyJAYIHAQhCEVZjAAFkoA7sgA5D5YeAGV9Ejx6si48fEIg4RxKCUE2LQj5RUYef5FJdnI4NDwSMjc-XC0UiRhDD0CURnx6IXLItwABhgTfAdETIAAkDEUylUGm06iYvxC5TMZmw4jA2BQtRSaVoGWwhSgi3iNz6d0RFSYwEpwCg8VwuOQAGEBncYABbenhCqKCzoCAweg5EY82h8gW7YAVAACAJw+EIFROMFR6G4Txe-FRMHRKF+ADE8KLsGc4MbBnB+mCGLdaIURWLaEwWjRVJUYL8KVTJbT6fQAKJUPkYVDM6wxDn0SjUOhMlnhznPMz2-mC0ZsnDoZDJ8XlalvWJQOOnTrDUOsiPlN4JT7fbiFsOFZXodDkmlIGLkKhl1Ml5AB6OEbvs+mV9vVr4IH5R7uNlWIoA)